Modern marvels- esque show or episode about alcohol
I use to see this all the time years ago on the history channel or similar channels. It was like a mini documentary about different types of alcohol, how it was made, and the history of the making of it and the company that produces it. I always thought it was similar to a modern marvels or how its made type show but I can't find any episode of modern marvels about alcohol. The one episode I remember vividly is one about the making of cognac in the cognac region of France and it mentioned the only water used in the making of any cognac came from a certain river or stream in this region of France. If anyone can find this for me that would be wonderful.

There are two "Modern Marvels" that cover distilleries:
Modern Marvels: Distilleries 2 This one mentions the Cognac in France in the summary.
The first one is: Modern Marvels: Distilleries.
